# How to launch web browser from client side

Tags: vb.net, browser, launch

I have a project with model client-server by visual basic language code windows form.
I create my server include all project code at iis server.
From client computer (without include project code only UI) run program and i want to open web browser and access to any link.
I have used process.start("url") and it run ok in local computer. But When i build code to .dll file and update to iis server it not run from client side.

```
Public Shared Sub TestOpenWeb(ByVal sender As WXSource, ByVal e As WXArgs)
        Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "https://www.google.com/")
    End Sub
```

Comment: *"When i build code to .dll file and update to iis server it not run from client side."* - Where exactly is this code executing?  If it's executing on the server then that would certainly explain why it's not executing on the client.  Because it's executing on the server.  Can you clarify?

Comment: This code is executed at the iis server, so I want to find a solution that when running that code, the client computer will open a website browser and access to my link.

Answer (score 0):

> When i build code to .dll file and update to iis server it not run from client side.

And further clarified in a comment on the question above...

> This code is executed at the iis server

Code that's executed on the server executes on the server, not on the client.  So currently you're opening a web browser *on the server*.

In the question you also mention...

> I have a project with model client-server by visual basic language code windows form.

If the client in this case is a Windows Forms application then it sounds like *that's* where you want to execute this code.

If you want to open a web browser on the client then you should be executing this `Process.Start()` operation in your *client* application, not the *server* application.